# Three Javascript Accordions on one page Two working

Tags: javascript, accordion

Hi tried to have multiple accordion on one page. Like three or six. 
But the second or fourth etc. is not working. 
Have somebody an idea?

Link: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GBYOZDRRVKFA

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Include a [mcve] in the question itself (preferable as [executable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are duplicating the same script 3 times. Keep the last one only and remove other script blocks.

**EDIT:**
This javascript won't work with dynamically generated html.
I have updated code with jQuery. Follow `<script>` tag inside `<head>`
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GC1V1TGM6QHJ

Magic happens with just 4 lines of script

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
//$(".accordion").click(function(){  
  $(document).on("click", ".accordion" , function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");    
    $(this).next(".panel").toggle();
  });
});
```

I suggest, once you are confident in JavaScript start learning jQuery alongside. It is very easy to learn and amazingly powerful. You can do a lot with less code.

Here is [step by step jQuery tutorial with interactive examples](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_intro.asp).
And here is a [Video tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhVDV697uvHpavA3K_eWGQap)

Comment: Thx a lot for your answer! Yes normally I would do it like you suggested but the problem is, that on my Wordpress page all the accordions are coming from an costum posttype. And are together on one page as a listing grid. If I'm putting the JS in the Footer/Header they are working fine (as in your example). But on the listing page you can filter the item. So the listing changes and the accordions are not opening anymore. That was the reason why every accordion has his own JS. But then just every second accordion will open. Do you maybe have an idea how to change the code to get it working?

Comment: if page changes dynamically, then this script won't work. You can use jQuery in your page to overcome this issue

Comment: Thank you!! Could you help me with the jQuery code? I'm a real beginner :(

Comment: You are awesome! Thx! But when I put it in my page the accordion is not working and my filters are not working too anymore ^^ I need to take all of it or? :)            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){  
  $(".accordion").click(function(){  
   $(this).toggleClass("active");    
   $(this).next(".panel").toggle();
  });
});


</script>

Comment: @Fritz yes you should take all that, which you mentioned in comment and put it inside head tag

Comment: I tried and yes the accordion is working fine, but my filters are not filtering anymore per Ajax. then I tried something with the jQuery.noConflict(); thing and the accordion worked quit well :) but no effect on the filter issues. do you have an idea?

Comment: Could it be that, when I filter the accordion elements per Ajax that I need to change the Jquery code that it needs to perform again? I read in the internet that sometimes it could be that per Ajax the j query renders before the html and that's the reason why it is not working? Do you every heard about something like that or have an idea? Because im unsung jet smart filters (plugin) for filtering // its hard to provide you the code I guess.

Comment: @Fritz actually we need `.on()` function of jQuery instead of `.click()` to work on dynamic content. I have edited my answer and replaced `click()` with `on()`. Please try this script. And one more thing, this script should be inside `<head>`

Comment: Wow!!!! it woks :D Thank you so much! You are the best! I promise to learn a lot about jQuery and maybe in the future I can help you :)

Comment: Sure :) . More power to you!!